# Jags/Bugs one step ahead prediction

Tags: mcmc, winbugs, jags

imagine a simple growth model.
How do I get the one step ahead predictions ??

```js
 # Priors and constraints
  N.est[1] ~ dunif(0, 10)  # Prior for initial population size
  mean.lambda ~ dunif(0, 10) # 
  mean.psi ~ dunif(0, 10) # 


  sigma.proc ~ dunif(0, 10)# Prior for sd of state process
  sigma2.proc <- pow(sigma.proc, 2)
  tau.proc <- pow(sigma.proc, -2)

  sigma.obs ~ dunif(0, 10)  # Prior for sd of observation process
  sigma2.obs <- pow(sigma.obs, 2)
  tau.obs <- pow(sigma.obs, -2)

  sigma.psi ~ dunif(0, 10)  # Prior for sd of observation process
  psi2.psi <- pow(sigma.psi, 2)
  tau.psi <- pow(sigma.psi, -2)

  # Likelihood
  # State process
  for (t in 1:(T-1)){
   lambda[t] ~ dnorm(mean.lambda, tau.proc)
   psi[t] ~ dnorm(mean.psi, tau.psi)

   N.est[t+1] <- 10/ ( 1+ exp(- psi[t] *(N.est[t] * lambda[t]) )  )   #N.est[t] * lambda[t] + psi[t]
  }
  # Observation process
  for (t in 1:T) {
   y[t] ~ dnorm(N.est[t], tau.obs)
  }
```

This is from a book, this example. How do I get the one step ahead predictions, because I am not interested in the smoothed output.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to simply set those units you want to predict in the response vector `y` to `NA` and then generate a replicate sample of `y`;

`y.pred[t] ~ dnorm(N.est[t], tau.obs)`

To check the residuals between `y` and `y.pred`

`res <- y - y.pred`

[Using JAGS in R with the rjags package](http://blue.for.msu.edu/CSTAT_13/exercises/exercise-1/ex-1.pdf)

Comment: thats true, but, imagine, you set the 6th sample to NA then you got the prediction of the 6th sample, but now you want to use the 6th sample to prediction the 7th and so on.
I am currently doing this by running the model with the 6th value set to NA, in the next run i set the 7th to NA and so on. This is not very practical. I was thinking about a simpler way.

Comment: Not sure I see the problem. You should set the 6th to the nth sample you want to predict to NA. The estimation is a markovian process, i.e. the 6th NA sample is estimated from the 5th data sample, the 7th NA sample will be estimated from the 6th (already) predicted sample etc...

Comment: Well, i think the 6th is predicted from the 1st to the 5th sample. since the current state should contain all information of the past. sure marcovian.
the 7th will be predicted from the 6th prediction which would make it the 2 steps ahead prediction.